# CAKeyframeAnimation beginTime

Tags: ios, iphone, caanimation

I'm writing a simple project to learn CAKeyframeAnimation's. I have a small UIView rectangle, item1, that I am moving across the screen.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *item1;
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender
{
CAKeyframeAnimation *animateItem1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
animateItem1.keyPath = @"position.x";
animateItem1.values = @[@0, @15, @113, @123, @135];
animateItem1.keyTimes = @[@0, @.50, @.80, @.90, @1.0];
animateItem1.duration = 4.;
// animateItem1.beginTime = 2.0;
animateItem1.additive = YES;
animateItem1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animateItem1.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.item1.layer addAnimation:animateItem1 forKey:@"move rect1"];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
self.item1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10)];
self.item1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.item1];
}
```

This runs as I expect it. But, if I un-comment the beginTime property. The animation just jumps to the end without executing each frame. After reading this explanation page, http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/, I'm simply expecting the animation to start and begin 2.0 seconds after I begin the animation. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What's the actual issue? You do or don't want it to have a delayed time? You say it runs as expected but when you comment it out it doesn't run as expected. Makes sense to me

Comment: This is the complete project, edited code presented. Anyone have an explanation for me? Thanks.